# Is Qur'an 4:118-119 considered as directly quoting Satan, or is it paraphrased?

Tags: tafseer, shaitan, surat-an-nisa

> They call upon instead of Him none but female [deities], and they [actually] call upon none but a rebellious Satan. Whom Allah has cursed. **For he had said, "I will surely take from among Your servants a specific portion. And I will mislead them, and I will arouse in them [sinful] desires, and I will command them so they will slit the ears of cattle, and I will command them so they will change the creation of Allah."** And whoever takes Satan as an ally instead of Allah has certainly sustained a clear loss.  -- [Qur'an 4:117-119](https://quran.com/4/117-119)

I'm wondering if this is (or is considered to be) a literal quote from Satan, i.e., Satan actually said those words, and his exact words are reproduced in the Qur'an.

**Question**: Is Qur'an 4:118-119 considered as directly quoting Satan?

I didn't find an answer by looking through altafsir.com.

It seems unnecessary, even counterproductive for Satan to declare his evil plans.  However, it may be that this were his initial plans, and they have evolved over time; I don't see many slitting the ears of cattle being particularly problematic nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quran to begin with is the speech of Allah.**

But in the verse you asked about, spoken words/Speech of shaytan is regarded by **Meaning** (as shaytan's) not by **Uttering** as you can conclude from the following points:

1- Even though Quran is the spoken word of Allah, the reported stories, and different speeches that Quran reports about previous nations, people, individuals or animals, are what they spoke, so from a **meaning perspective** it's theirs.

2- Languages of previous nations, or individuals were not Arabic, so it is Allah who is narrating their speech and stories in Quran which is ** in Arabic**.

### Two types of Speech:

A- meaning and Wording: The Speech delivered with same wording, exactly as is, without changing the semantics, meanings, or words.

B- Meaning Only: When you report (narrate) a story or a speech, with different wording or style in narration, the **speech is yours** verbally and orally, while meaning is the original speaker's.

### The Best of Stories

> 12-3 We tell you [Prophet] the best of stories in revealing this Quran
>   to you. Before this you were one of those who knew nothing about them.

Shaytan

To explain how Allah narrated the stories, consider the following example:

> 15-33 He said, "Never would I prostrate to a human whom You created
>   out of clay from an altered black mud."

The same is being told in sura Al-Araf:

> 7-12 [ Allah ] said, "What prevented you from prostrating when I
>   commanded you?" [Satan] said, "I am better than him. You created me
>   from fire and created him from clay."

**Same story**, **different wording**(Speech of Allah), **One meaning** (What shaytan replied to Allah).

And Allah knows best.